# Djano heroku deployment issue: django

Tags: python, django, heroku

First time here on stackowerflow, hoping somebody will be able to help me :)

I have tried several ways to deploy site, following several tutorials and had solved most of errors I got except one:

After pushing django project via git to heroku, I have error with app crashing (https://vocnjak.herokuapp.com/). Logs give error H10 and in logs:

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application,
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'

Here are logs:

[Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3Wd2.png)

Also when I run heroku run python manage.py migrate I get:

```
ImportError: Couldn&apos;t import Django. Are you sure it&apos;s installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
```

I have installed Django and all dependencies in virtual environment, and Django site is working when run locally (as python manage.py runserver) and that is bugging me.

Procfile:

```
web: gunicorn vocnjak.wsgi --log-file -
```

requierments.txt (with everything installed):

```
asgiref==3.5.0
backports.zoneinfo==0.2.1
dj-database-url==0.5.0
Django==4.0.1
django-crispy-forms==1.14.0
django-heroku==0.3.1
gunicorn==20.1.0
psycopg2==2.9.3
psycopg2-binary==2.9.3
pytz==2021.3
sqlparse==0.4.2
whitenoise==5.3.0
```

Thanks!

Edit:

Pipfile:

```
[[source]]
url = "https://pypi.python.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"

[packages]
requests = "*"
gunicorn = "*"
whitenoise = "*"

[dev-packages]

[requires]
python_version = "3.8"
```

Pipfile.lock:

```
{
    "_meta": {
        "hash": {
            "sha256": "5e91acc60bf7724e6c2b1e135c2840490be35fe168f9290b78370a9a1bf2de7f"
        },
        "pipfile-spec": 6,
        "requires": {
            "python_version": "3.8"
        },
        "sources": [
            {
                "name": "pypi",
                "url": "https://pypi.python.org/simple",
                "verify_ssl": true
            }
        ]
    },
    "default": {
        "certifi": {
            "hashes": [
                "sha256:78884e7c1d4b00ce3cea67b44566851c4343c120abd683433ce934a68ea58872",
                "sha256:d62a0163eb4c2344ac042ab2bdf75399a71a2d8c7d47eac2e2ee91b9d6339569"
            ],
            "version": "==2021.10.8"
        },
        "charset-normalizer": {
            "hashes": [
                "sha256:876d180e9d7432c5d1dfd4c5d26b72f099d503e8fcc0feb7532c9289be60fcbd",
                "sha256:cb957888737fc0bbcd78e3df769addb41fd1ff8cf950dc9e7ad7793f1bf44455"
            ],
            "markers": "python_version >= '3'",
            "version": "==2.0.10"
        },
        "gunicorn": {
            "hashes": [
                "sha256:9dcc4547dbb1cb284accfb15ab5667a0e5d1881cc443e0677b4882a4067a807e",
                "sha256:e0a968b5ba15f8a328fdfd7ab1fcb5af4470c28aaf7e55df02a99bc13138e6e8"
            ],
            "index": "pypi",
            "version": "==20.1.0"
        },
        "idna": {
            "hashes": [
                "sha256:84d9dd047ffa80596e0f246e2eab0b391788b0503584e8945f2368256d2735ff",
                "sha256:9d643ff0a55b762d5cdb124b8eaa99c66322e2157b69160bc32796e824360e6d"
            ],
            "markers": "python_version >= '3'",
            "version": "==3.3"
        },
        "requests": {
            "hashes": [
                "sha256:68d7c56fd5a8999887728ef304a6d12edc7be74f1cfa47714fc8b414525c9a61",
                "sha256:f22fa1e554c9ddfd16e6e41ac79759e17be9e492b3587efa038054674760e72d"
            ],
            "index": "pypi",
            "version": "==2.27.1"
        },
        "urllib3": {
            "hashes": [
                "sha256:4987c65554f7a2dbf30c18fd48778ef124af6fab771a377103da0585e2336ece",
                "sha256:c4fdf4019605b6e5423637e01bc9fe4daef873709a7973e195ceba0a62bbc844"
            ],
            "version": "==1.26.7"
        },
        "whitenoise": {
            "hashes": [
                "sha256:d234b871b52271ae7ed6d9da47ffe857c76568f11dd30e28e18c5869dbd11e12",
                "sha256:d963ef25639d1417e8a247be36e6aedd8c7c6f0a08adcb5a89146980a96b577c"
            ],
            "index": "pypi",
            "version": "==5.3.0"
        }
    },
    "develop": {}
}
```

Comment: Do you have a `Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock`?

Comment: Yes, I do have both

Comment: Then your `requirements.txt` is irrelevant. Please [edit] your question and add your `Pipfile`.

Comment: Please see the linked duplicate. TL;DR, Heroku is installing from your `Pipfile` / `Pipfile.lock` and ignoring your `requirements.txt`.

Comment: That did it! Finally have it running. Thank you very very much!